# TypeScript - Array.map of custom class elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, class

I'm having an issue with an array elements of a custom class.

My class is defined as:

```
export class Alarm {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    time: string;
    days: string[];

    //My custom methods....

    constructor (values: Object = {}){
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

In my (Angular) component, I have defined an array of Alarm objects

```
var alarms: Alarm[] = [
    new Alarm({ name: "Alarm 1", time: "06:55", days: ["MO", "TU"] }),
    new Alarm({ name: "Alarm 2", time: "06:56", days: ["MO", "TU"] }),
    new Alarm({ name: "Alarm 3", time: "06:57", days: ["MO", "TU"] }),
    new Alarm({ name: "WAKE UP!", time: "06:58", days: ["MO", "TU"] })
];
```

And if I inspect the array, I can see that all elements are Alarm objects.

However, if I try to get an Alarm index, starting from an ID, with:

```
var alarmPosition = this.alarms.map((alarm) => alarm.id == id).indexOf(true);
```

after this instruction my array is now populated by Object elements, so without any Alarm method defined in the class.

Now, I thought that the *map* function wouldn't modify the original array, and even if it did, why do my Alarm object become "simple" Objects?

Comment: Which version of TypeScript?

Comment: @Razem it's 2.7.2

Comment: `this.alarms.map((alarm) => alarm.id == id)` won't change the content of `this.alarms`. Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Well, it works for me locally. As @Andreas suggested, you should make a complete example with your current configuration.

Comment: It looks like `this.alarms.map` is not `map() { [native code] }` (which is the default Array map function), but it calls a function of a node_module instead. And I think this function is different from the Array.map method, and overrides the original array.

Comment: I think this is the cause why they are casted to objects finally => `constructor (values: Object = { }) { }`

Answer (score 6):

`map` will result in new array.  Try using `find`/`filter` depending on what you are looking for.

```
// Finds an alarm with given ID
var alarm = this.alarms.find((alarm) => alarm.id === id);

// Finds all alarms with given ID
var alarms = this.alarms.filter((alarm) => alarm.id === id);
```

Comment: I know that map returns a new array, the problem here is that my ORIGINAL array has changed, even if I haven't assigned the returned value to it

Comment: No - original array will not change if you use `map` unless you assign what is returned from `map` to that array

Comment: And as you can see from my question, `var alarmPosition = this.alarms.map(...)` doesn't assign the returned value to the original array, it declares a new variable instead

Comment: Unrelated to this exact problem, but... That totally depends on the callback used: `[{a: 1}, {a: 2}].map((_, index, array) => array[index].a++);`

Comment: @LucaDeNardi - In your example, `Alarm` objects don't have ID - however you are comparing using them in `map`. Can you share class `Alarm` code?  Are you using any other framwork other than what you listed? Where are you getting `alarms` array?  The code that you have shared does not modify `alarms` array - I have validated that part.

Comment: @WandMaker the ID is calculated within the class.. Upon a deeper inspection, I found out that the issue was generated by the ngx-store node_module that saves Angular variable on the LocalStorage to be easily restored upon page load. It also overwrite the standard array functions, like the map method, with a custom function that actually modifies the original array.